# AJAX with Rails - Missing Template

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to get AJAX working on my app and am getting a strange `ActionView::MissingTemplate` error.  I have this as my `tasks#create` method:

```
def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)
    @task.user_id = current_user.id
    if @task.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html
      end
    #   redirect_to tasks_path, notice: 'Task was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

This as my `views/tasks/create.js.erb`:

```
$("#onetime-todo").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'items', locals: { task: @one_time }) %>")
$("#onetime-done").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'done', locals: { task: @one_time_done }) %>")

$("#daily-todo").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'items', locals: { task: @daily }) %>")
$("#daily-done").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'done', locals: { task: @daily_done }) %>")

$("#weekly-todo").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'items', locals: { task: @weekly }) %>")
$("#weekly-done").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'done', locals: { task: @weekly_done }) %>")

$("#monthly-todo").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'items', locals: { task: @monthly }) %>")
$("#monthly-done").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'done', locals: { task: @monthly_done }) %>")
```

And this on my `tasks/index.html.erb`:

```
            <%= simple_form_for(@create_task) do |f| %>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                            <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "What needs to get done?", class: "form-control" %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                            <%= f.select :frequency, options_for_select([["One-Time", "OneTime"],["Daily", "Daily"],["Weekly", "Weekly"],["Monthly", "Monthly"]]), {}, {class: "form-control"} %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                            <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn ghost", remote: true %>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- container -->
                </div> <!-- row -->
            <% end %>

....

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12">
        <div class="content-box border-green">
          <h1>One-Time Tasks</h1>
                <div id="onetime-todo"><%= render partial: 'items', locals: { task: @one_time } %></div>
                <div id="onetime-done"><%= render partial: 'done', locals: { task: @one_time_done } %></div>
        </div> <!-- content box -->
        </div> <!-- col -->

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="content-box">
          <h1>Daily</h1>
          <div id="daily-todo"><%= render partial: 'items', locals: { task: @daily } %></div>
          <div id="daily-done"><%= render partial: 'done', locals: { task: @daily_done } %></div>
        </div> <!-- content box -->
        </div> <!-- col -->

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="content-box">
          <h1>Weekly</h1>
          <div id="weekly-todo"><%= render partial: 'items', locals: { task: @weekly } %></div>
          <div id="weekly-done"><%= render partial: 'done', locals: { task: @weekly_done } %></div>
        </div> <!-- content box -->
        </div> <!-- col -->

        <div class="col-xs-12  col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="content-box">
          <h1>Montly</h1>
          <div id="monthly-todo"><%= render partial: 'items', locals: { task: @monthly } %></div>
           <div id="monthly-done"><%= render partial: 'done', locals: { task: @monthly_done } %></div>
        </div> <!-- content box -->
        </div> <!-- col -->
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?  It seems like a weird error because I **do** have a create template.  My server log shows this:

```
Started POST "/tasks" for ::1 at 2017-08-13 21:48:44 -0700
Processing by TasksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"guwmQBf1AmKhxvi1coysoegbkKhy6Znk/oMKEar4TXcZ1OieTqiyRnf3m3MR/XHBrOsJ1d7ncZp8pzqAxC93tQ==", "task"=>{"name"=>"Testing oh testing", "frequency"=>"OneTime"}, "commit"=>"Create Task"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "tasks" ("name", "frequency", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Testing oh testing"], ["frequency", "OneTime"], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2017-08-14 04:48:44.237114"], ["updated_at", "2017-08-14 04:48:44.237114"]]
   (2.0ms)  commit transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 13ms (ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)

ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing template tasks/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/lizbayardelle/Dropbox/Code/FAM/app/views"
  * "/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/ckeditor-4.2.2/app/views"
  * "/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/devise-4.2.0/app/views"
```

And my `routes.rb` are very simple, if it helps:

resources :tasks

Can anyone help here?

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

As requested, here is my `tasks#index` method:

```
  def index
    @create_task = Task.new
    @tasks = Task.all
    @one_time = Task.where(frequency: "OneTime", completed: false, user_id: current_user.id)
    @one_time_done = Task.where(frequency: "OneTime", completed: true, user_id: current_user.id)
    @daily = Task.where(frequency: "Daily", completed: false, user_id: current_user.id)
    @daily_done = Task.where(frequency: "Daily", completed: true, user_id: current_user.id)
    @weekly = Task.where(frequency: "Weekly", completed: false, user_id: current_user.id)
    @weekly_done = Task.where(frequency: "Weekly", completed: true, user_id: current_user.id)
    @monthly = Task.where(frequency: "Monthly", completed: false, user_id: current_user.id)
    @monthly_done = Task.where(frequency: "Monthly", completed: true, user_id: current_user.id)
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to get AJAX working on my app and am getting a strange
>   `ActionView::MissingTemplate` error.

The request is being made as *HTML*, that is, the `remote: true` in the submit `button` is not working, try setting it in the `form` tag, like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@create_task), remote: true do |f| %>
```

---

> I'm getting this error in my server:
>
> > Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 28ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
> >     NoMethodError - undefined method each' for nil:NilClass:
> >     app/views/tasks/_items.html.erb:2:in
> >     _app_views_tasks__items_html_erb__1746796241772610323_702981‌​03116960'

The problem is that all variables that are required in *create.js.erb* have not being set in `create` action, they are only set in `index`. So you need to create all those variables also in `create`, but you can avoid repetition using a `before_action` callback, like this:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_variables, only: [:index, :create]

  def index
  end

  def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)
    @task.user_id = current_user.id
    if @task.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html
      end
    #   redirect_to tasks_path, notice: 'Task was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # other actions
  private
  def set_variables
    @create_task = Task.new
    @tasks = Task.all
    @one_time = Task.where(frequency: "OneTime", completed: false, user_id: current_user.id)
    @one_time_done = Task.where(frequency: "OneTime", completed: true, user_id: current_user.id)
    @daily = Task.where(frequency: "Daily", completed: false, user_id: current_user.id)
    @daily_done = Task.where(frequency: "Daily", completed: true, user_id: current_user.id)
    @weekly = Task.where(frequency: "Weekly", completed: false, user_id: current_user.id)
    @weekly_done = Task.where(frequency: "Weekly", completed: true, user_id: current_user.id)
    @monthly = Task.where(frequency: "Monthly", completed: false, user_id: current_user.id)
    @monthly_done = Task.where(frequency: "Monthly", completed: true, user_id: current_user.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: This got rid of the errors and made it create the task correctly, but I still had to hit refresh for it to appear on the page...

Comment: @Liz No change at all? Any error messages in the server log or browser console? Also, verify `create.js.erb`, you're rendering `items` partial when you should be rendering (i guess) `done`.

Comment: @Liz One more thing, be sure to verify that all variables you create in `index` (e.g. `@one_time`, `@one_time_done`, `@daily`, etc.) are also created in `create`.

Comment: I'm getting this error in my server: `Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 28ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)

NoMethodError - undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass:
  app/views/tasks/_items.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_tasks__items_html_erb__1746796241772610323_70298103116960'`...which points to this line in my `_items` partial:  `<% task.each do |task| %>`

Comment: @Liz `task` is not being set, that is, some `@` variable is not being created in `create` action, thus `task` is `nil`. Check those variables. Can you post show the complete controller code?

Comment: Everything is being done via partials.  So the `task` in the problem line is being passed in as a local (see the `create.js.erb`) as `@one_time` or `@daily`, etc.

Comment: @Liz, exactly, so `@one_time` or `@daily` (or some other variable) is `nil` and that value gets to the partial, that is why you need to check how you set those variables in `index` and confirm that you are doing the same for `create`.

Comment: As requested, I added the `tasks#index` method to the OP.

Comment: @Liz There's the problem all `@` variables  are set on `index` but not on `create` action, so when you do this: `locals: { task: @one_time })` in _create.js.html_ is the same as doing `locals: { task: nil })` because `@one_time ` is not being set.

Comment: Okay, it works if I put all those variables in the `create` method too.  Should it be clearing the form automatically or is that something I have to spell out in `create.js.erb`?

Comment: @Liz No, you should do it on `create.js.erb`, remeber that doing AJAX will only update the page where you specifically tell the script, otherwise it will remain unchanged.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @Liz Glad to help! Happy coding!