# Rails AJAX Missing Template Error with link_to Delete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to AJAX-ify a to do type app and just finished dealing with this problem for my `create` method (see [here][1]).  Now the `delete` method is acting up, but I can't use the previous solution (moving the `remote: true` from the submit to the `form_for` line) because the deletion is done via `link_to`.

Here's my `tasks#index` action:

```
  def index
    @create_task = Task.new
    @tasks = Task.all
    @one_time = Task.where(frequency: "OneTime", completed: false, user_id: current_user.id)
    @one_time_done = Task.where(frequency: "OneTime", completed: true, user_id: current_user.id)
    @daily = Task.where(frequency: "Daily", completed: false, user_id: current_user.id)
    @daily_done = Task.where(frequency: "Daily", completed: true, user_id: current_user.id)
    @weekly = Task.where(frequency: "Weekly", completed: false, user_id: current_user.id)
    @weekly_done = Task.where(frequency: "Weekly", completed: true, user_id: current_user.id)
    @monthly = Task.where(frequency: "Monthly", completed: false, user_id: current_user.id)
    @monthly_done = Task.where(frequency: "Monthly", completed: true, user_id: current_user.id)
  end
```

And my `tasks#destroy` action:

```
  def destroy
    @one_time = Task.where(frequency: "OneTime", completed: false, user_id: current_user.id)
    @one_time_done = Task.where(frequency: "OneTime", completed: true, user_id: current_user.id)
    @daily = Task.where(frequency: "Daily", completed: false, user_id: current_user.id)
    @daily_done = Task.where(frequency: "Daily", completed: true, user_id: current_user.id)
    @weekly = Task.where(frequency: "Weekly", completed: false, user_id: current_user.id)
    @weekly_done = Task.where(frequency: "Weekly", completed: true, user_id: current_user.id)
    @monthly = Task.where(frequency: "Monthly", completed: false, user_id: current_user.id)
    @monthly_done = Task.where(frequency: "Monthly", completed: true, user_id: current_user.id)

    if @task.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.js
          format.html
      end
    else
      flash[:warning] = "Oops! Something went wrong!"
    end

  end
  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667684/ajax-with-rails-missing-template
```

Here is my delete `link_to` (from a partial):

```
   <%= link_to task_path(task), method: :delete, remote: true do %>
        <i class="icon ion-close-circled" id=(task.id + "task") style="margin-left: 5px"></i>
   <% end %>
```

Rendered on `tasks/index.html.erb` like so:

```
<div id="onetime-todo"><%= render partial: 'items', locals: { task: @one_time } %></div>
```

Here's my `delete.js.erb`:

```
$("#onetime-todo").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'items', locals: { task: @one_time }) %>")
$("#onetime-done").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'done', locals: { task: @one_time_done }) %>")

$("#daily-todo").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'items', locals: { task: @daily }) %>")
$("#daily-done").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'done', locals: { task: @daily_done }) %>")

$("#weekly-todo").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'items', locals: { task: @weekly }) %>")
$("#weekly-done").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'done', locals: { task: @weekly_done }) %>")

$("#monthly-todo").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'items', locals: { task: @monthly }) %>")
$("#monthly-done").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'done', locals: { task: @monthly_done }) %>")
```

And finally my irritating server log:

```
Started DELETE "/tasks/1" for ::1 at 2017-08-14 12:59:40 -0700
Processing by TasksController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Task Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."id" = ?  [["id", 1]]
   (0.6ms)  commit transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)

ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing template tasks/destroy, application/destroy with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/lizbayardelle/Dropbox/Code/FAM/app/views"
  * "/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/ckeditor-4.2.2/app/views"
  * "/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/devise-4.2.0/app/views"
:
```

It bothers me that this error keeps occurring with each method.  The deletion does happen, it just necessitates a refresh to appear on the page.  Anyone see what's happening here?

Comment: perhaps you want `delete.js.erb` to be `destroy.js.erb` since the action is `destroy`, not `delete`.

Comment: @jvillian, well that was easy.  Moron moment.  Wanna write up the answer so I can pick it.

Comment: No problems. Happens to the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `delete.js.erb` to be `destroy.js.erb` since the action is `destroy`, not `delete`.